# Global variables in Intellij templates

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity

I am trying to create some variables similar to the predefined ones that come with the IntelliJ templating system. I am looking to create a variable called $MY_NAME_AND_EMAIL where I can define it once and then reference it in different templates. Is this possible?

I have tried creating an include called `AuthorName.txt`:

```
#set($MY_NAME_AND_EMAIL = "Name <email@example.com>")
```

Then, in one of my templates, I put the following line at the top:

```
#parse("AuthorName.txt")
```

Further down the file, I use ${MY_NAME_AND_EMAIL} in the header. However, when I create a new file base on that template, it still prompts me for the name and email field, even though I set it in an include file and added the `#parse` directive. What am I doing wrong?